# What software can be used for rapid texturing?

Tags: windows-7, 3d, graphic-design

In the open source content in 3D, Blender is the humongous software for anything. It is a complete animation suite. But, When It comes to texturing 3D models all the procedurals or UV unwrapping can be pretty time consuming. Are there any open source softwares out there that can help us in rapid texturing, like some built in image textures that can be applied(like procedurals) right off the shelf. It can be termed as object oriented texturing. I'm looking for windows platform and open source.